# how can i achieve Null row after every sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
declare @t table (val int)

insert INto @t (val) values (420), (420), (520), (520), (520), (620)

select 
    val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val order by val) RN 
from @t
```

Returns output:

```
val RN
------
420 1
420 2
520 1
520 2
520 3
620 1
```

Desired output :

```
val RN
420 1
420 2
NULL NULL
520 1
520 2
520 3
NULL NULL
620 1
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @NickBailey i need to show as summary for different sequences i know to use WITH ROLLUP but it will give Sum values

Comment: Show a summary in what application. This sort of display logic belongs in your application layer

Comment: in the application side just rendering the values what i show just bind in the application side.Summary is like District wise supplies i just gave sample data @NickBailey

Comment: well then change your application code

Comment: The only way to put those nulls in is with a loop and a union, something that the application will be much more efficient at doing. I'd suggest modifying the record set before sending it off to your grid or what-have-you on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
declare @t table (val int)
declare @n table( val int)

insert INTO @n(val) values( NULL )
insert INto @t (val)values (420),(420),(520),(520),(520),(620)

SELECT T2.val, T2.RN AS RN
FROM (
select T.val AS GRP, T.val,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.val order by T.val)RN from @t AS T
union
select DISTINCT T.VAL AS GRP, NULL AS val, NULL AS RN FROM @t AS T
) AS T2
ORDER BY T2.GRP, ISNULL(T2.RN, 99)
```

To have a summary row change the main SELECT:

```
SELECT T2.val, T2.RN AS RN
FROM (
select T.val AS GRP, T.val,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.val order by     T.val) RN from @t AS T
union 
select T.VAL AS GRP, SUM(T.VAL) AS val, NULL AS RN FROM @t AS T GROUP BY T.Val
) AS T2
ORDER BY T2.GRP, ISNULL(T2.RN, 99)
```

Comment: my answers caption is "This works:", I am simply saying that my answer works, is it a robust one?  no but you can solve the order by issue easily enough.  =)

Comment: yeah i agree with you is there any possibility that we can do summary for each sequence

Comment: yeah, you could just do another UNION and use the GRP column to "group" them together.

Comment: what are you summarizing?  the number of records per val?

Comment: total of val 420 + 420 = 840 like that total of each sequence

Comment: if i'm going to ask new question moderators will mark as duplicate buddy what i need to do

Answer (score 3):

This type of manipulation should really be done in the application.  You can do this in SQL Server, but it is really more of an amusing trick, then a recommended answer.

The idea is to join in the rows you want and then use `order by` to get the results in order:

```
select val, rn
from ((select val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val order by val) as rn,
              1 as ordering, val as val2
       from @t t
      ) union all
      (select NULL, NULL, 2, val
       from @t t
       group by val
      )
     ) t
order by val2, ordering, rn;
```

Let me emphasize that this is a demonstration of the power of the `select` statement.  The real answer is to do this at the application layer.

Comment: yeah we can achieve this in front end but i'm just thinking of possibilities in T-SQL side but here is the code i'm looking for

Comment: You can lose the extra NULL row at the end by adding HAVING val <> (select max(val) from @t) after the group by.

Comment: is there any possibility of achieving summary for each sequence

Comment: @mohan111 . . . Use `rollup` or `grouping sets`.  These are the intended functions for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

We all hate cursors, but for something this silly and hopefully with a small dataset you can brute force it in sql instead of in the app layer. But it feels dumb. But you can you it.

For what it worth, this solution avoids the "extra" NULL row at the the end. Therefore it technically matches your desired output exactly. The others don't quite so far.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (val INT)
INSERT INTO @t (val) VALUES (420),(420),(520),(520),(520),(620)
--SELECT val,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY val order by val)RN from @t


DECLARE @t2 table (id INT identity(1,1), val INT, rn INT)

DECLARE @val INT
DECLARE @rn INT
DECLARE @val_prev INT


DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT val
      ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY val ORDER BY val)RN 
  FROM @t 
  ORDER BY val ASC

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
INTO @val, @rn

SET @val_prev = @val

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  IF @val_prev <> @val BEGIN
     INSERT @t2 (val,rn) VALUES (NULL, NULL)
     SET @val_prev = @val
  END

  INSERT @t2 (val,rn) VALUES (@val, @rn)
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
  INTO @val, @rn
END 
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

SELECT * FROM @t2 ORDER BY id
```